# Clean Phone Number String

Tags: string, imacros

I have something like this

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:crm_case_add ATTR=ID:CrmCasePhoneNumber EXTRACT=TXT
```

All the phone numbers are in this format: 800-128-1990 or (800)128-1981 or 291 399 5913

I want it plain text like 8002893884. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line into your macro:

```
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/[-()\\s]/g,'')")
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to do in SQL

I use a function to clean up phone numbers which will fix all phone number issues or clears the field.  Returns Null if Blank (To prevent Errors)

```
Print'/*Fix Phone Numbers Call*/'
Update tblTemp
    Set Phone = dbo.fnPhoneFix(tblTemp.Phone)
From tblTemp
```

To Create the Fuction use the following code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnPhoneFix](@PhoneOld VarChar(20))
    Returns VarChar(10)
AS
    Begin
    Declare @iCnt Int = 0
    Declare @PhoneNew VarChar(15)  = ''

    IF @PhoneOld IS NULL
        RETURN NULL;

    While @iCnt <= LEN(@PhoneOld)
        Begin
            IF Substring(@PhoneOld,@iCnt,1) >= '0' AND Substring(@PhoneOld,@iCnt,1) <= '9'
            Begin
                SET @PhoneNew = @PhoneNew + Substring(@PhoneOld,@iCnt,1)
            End
            Set @iCnt = @iCnt + 1
        End

    If LEN(@PhoneNew) > 10 and Left(@PhoneNew, 1) = '1'
        Set @PhoneNew = RIGHT(@PhoneNew,10);
    Else
        Set @PhoneNew = Left(@PhoneNew,10);

    If LEN(@PhoneNew) <> 10
        Set @PhoneNew ='';
    Return @PhoneNew
End
```